# python os.getenv('APPDATA') returns none - os.environ does not have APPDATA listed in the data dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables

What happened here? Why did this disappear? It was working fine earlier today.  I can look in the windows environment variables and see it listed there still for system and user environemtn variables, but it no longer shows up in the python command.  I deleted the .pyc file as well, but still no go?  How do I get it back?

Comment: Insufficient information. If you start a shell does it show the var?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by 'start a shell'? Do you mean like run python.exe and do "import os print(os.getenv('APPDATA'))"  ?  I tried that, and it does work.  I'm using VSCode as my editor, and when it registers os environment variables appdata is not listed.